# How do you get the name of the Discord interaction field?

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make a command that has an optional amount of inputs out of 7 where the user chooses a field, then inputs whatever value they want. I am then trying to get name of the input, as well as the input value.

Here is my code:

```
@bot.tree.command(name='getchar', description='Get all the information about an NPC')
async def getchar (interaction: discord.Interaction, name: str = None, residence: str = None, age: int = None):
  print({name}, {residence}, {age})
  await interaction.response.send_message(f'name: {name}, residence: {residence}, age: {age}')
```

EG: If the user puts in "/getchar name:test age:40" I want to be able to then have an array that stores the info like "{name, 'test', age, 40} so I can use it for something later on. I can get the values no problem, but how would I go about getting the name (name, age, residence etc) dynamically?

Thanks!

Comment: Check [interaction.data](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction.data).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [interaction.data](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction.data) like @Chrisspray said. If you meant with getting the arguments dynamically that you want to use them in another piece of code like another command, you'll need to save them to a variable that is globally accessable (e.g `bot.user_data[user.id] = {name: "test", age: 40}`.

In addition to that you'll have to declare this field in your code before the bot starts (e.g. `bot.user_data = []`).

### Persistent Data

If you want to use the entered data between bot restarts, you'll have to store them somewhere. Data like this is normally stored in [databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database).

Databases are used to store high amounts of data in "tables". A table has a set amount of rows and columns, each column named with the data it stores. One row is the equivalent to one set of data, for example a users name, address or email.

There are many database systems out there, but the one fitting for you at this moment would be SQLite, a file based database. Most of the other databases require a server, while SQLite just needs a file, for example in your bots directory.

If you want to use said database, you can look through this tutorial, explaining the basics of SQLite in python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html